# RubyMine (Jetbrains) cancel copy text by only highlighting the text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, centos, rubymine, jetbrains-ide

I'm using RubyMine 6.3.3 under CentOS 6,
I find it very annoying that by highlighting a text it automatically copy's the whole text..

especially when I want to paste over a specific (and highlighted) area.

I searched around the web and couldn't find where I can disable that option.

can anyone here help?

Comment: This sounds more like a OS config/issue -- AFAIK RubyMine has no such option. most likely you are doing "middle click" accidentally (are you using mouse or touchpad?)

Comment: From http://www.linuxclues.com/articles/13.htm -- *"Use your cursor to select the text you want to copy. In Linux, that automatically copies the text to the clipboard."*

Comment: @LazyOne, you are right, it might be a OS problem - using CentOS 6

Comment: Check your Gnome/KDE settings (Keyboard/Mouse settings?) -- maybe you will find an option to turn it off. I'm not Linux user myself, unfortunately, and cannot really help more than this.